# Mandl & Shaw QFT chapter 1 question

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, differentiation

Page 3 of Mandl & Shaw claims that, given a vector $\pmb{A}(\pmb{x},t)=\pmb{A}_{0}e^{i(\pmb{k}\pmb{\cdot} \pmb{x} - \omega t)}$, $\pmb{\nabla} \pmb{\cdot} \pmb{A} = 0$ (eq. 1.6) implies $\pmb{k} \pmb{\cdot}
\pmb{A} = 0$ (eq. 1.7).

I'm having trouble figuring out why (1.6) implies (1.7).

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{A}=\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z}=i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{A}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can just take the derivative of the exponential. In particular:

$$
\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{A}(t,\vec{x})=\vec{A}_0 \cdot \vec{\nabla} e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t)} = i \vec{k}\cdot\vec{A}_0e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t)} = i \vec{k}\cdot\vec{A}(t,\vec{x}) = 0\,.
$$
There you go!

Comment: beat me to it :)

Comment: Ahaha sorry about that! :)